# Type of field for prefix search in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, prefix

I'm confused on what index type I should apply for my field for prefix search, many show search_as_you_type but I think auto complete is not what I'm going for.

I have a UUID field:

```
id: 34y72ca1-3739-41ff-bbec-f6d17479384c
```

The following terms should return the doc above:

3

34

34y72ca1

34y72ca1-3739

34y72ca1-3739-41ff-bbec-f6d17479384c

Using 3739 should not return it as it doesn't start with 3739. Initially this is what I was going for but then the wildcard field is not supported by Amazon AWS, so I compromise for prefix search instead of partial search.

I tried search_as_you_type field but it doesn't return the result when I use the whole ID. Actually, my use case is when user click enter, the results will be shown, instead of real-live when they type, so if speed is compromised its OK, just that I hope for something that will be good for many rows of data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not explicitly defined any index mapping, then you need to use `id.keyword` field instead of the `id` field for the prefix query to show the appropriate results.  This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "id.keyword": {
        "value": "34y72ca1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can modify your index mapping, by adding [multi fields for `id` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex)

Comment: so u suggest that I use keyword type only?

Comment: @nanakondor based on your requirement given in the question above, you can use `keyword` type